# why id changed to _id when I use rails cache to get data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, grape-api

I'm using Rails with grape and Mongo, I wanna use Rails cache to optimize performance, and this is my code:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 1.hour) do
    render_template('chatrooms/info', {chatroom: chatroom, user:current_user, group: chatroom.group})
end
```

the cache is valid, but the return data changed.

add cache before, return data is:

```
chatroom: {
   name: "磁场",
   id: "573c025cc5ffa353c7000000",
   owner_id: "56a8b4c9feec620985000000",
   avatar: "http://o2zuoh5os.qnssl.com/icon_magnet.png"
}
```

otherwise, after adding cache, return data is:

```
chatroom: {
   name: "磁场",
   _id: "573c025cc5ffa353c7000000",
   owner_id: "56a8b4c9feec620985000000",
   avatar: "http://o2zuoh5os.qnssl.com/icon_magnet.png"
}
```

the 'id' field changed to '_id'

I don't know what happened, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

@wind so basically mongoDB create `_id` field for every document. In mongoid they specifically alias the _id attribute & setter/getter methods to `id`

This is the code snippet from [`mongoid-6.0.2/lib/mongoid/fields.rb`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/fd596c2cbe865afa7a2806d658497499b8744540/lib/mongoid/fields.rb#L47-L62) file

```
  self.aliased_fields = { "id" => "_id" }
  self.fields = {}
  self.localized_fields = {}
  self.pre_processed_defaults = []
  self.post_processed_defaults = []

  field(
    :_id,
    default: ->{ BSON::ObjectId.new },
    pre_processed: true,
    type: BSON::ObjectId
  )

  alias :id :_id
  alias :id= :_id=
end
```

So, both id & _id are same thing here, its just which code prefers which one.